# Pandas - get the mean of one column using descending N rows of another column

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
             team        opponent home_dummy     round     points
0     Athlético-PR       Flamengo          0        13      22.91
1     Athlético-PR    Atlético-GO          0        17       23.6
2     Athlético-PR      Fortaleza          1        20      28.58
3     Athlético-PR      Fortaleza          0         1      75.71
4     Athlético-PR          Ceará          1        14      42.22
5     Athlético-PR       Coritiba          1        10      52.91
6     Athlético-PR          Goiás          1         2      39.82
7     Athlético-PR          Goiás          0        21      65.13
8     Athlético-PR  Internacional          0        15      43.09
9     Athlético-PR         Grêmio          1        18      15.38
10    Athlético-PR          Sport          0        19      13.09
11    Athlético-PR         Santos          1        22      65.45
12    Athlético-PR         Santos          0         3      28.04
13    Athlético-PR      Palmeiras          1         4      -7.31
14    Athlético-PR      Palmeiras          0        23      11.02
15    Athlético-PR          Vasco          0         8      15.93
16    Athlético-PR     Fluminense          1         5       9.16
17    Athlético-PR          Bahia          1        12      59.78
18    Athlético-PR    Corinthians          1        16      18.22
19    Athlético-PR       Botafogo          1         9      29.35
20    Athlético-PR     Bragantino          1         7      20.07
.......
```

The dataframe above has another 19 teams, other than 'Athlético-PR'.

---

How do I group this dataframe, getting, for each team:

1. Mean points for the last N rounds, say N=6, which would get the mean of round `23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18`.
2. Mean points for the last N rounds passing 'home_dummy' as condition, which would get the mean of either rounds `23, 21, 19, 17, 15, 13` or rounds `22, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12`.

ending up with:

```
    team           mean_total   mean_home_0   mean_home_1
 0  Athlético-PR       mean x        mean y        mean z
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can to do two separate groupby:

```
df = df.sort_values(['team','round'])

out = (df.groupby(['team','home_dummy']).tail(6)
         .groupby(['team','home_dummy'])['points'].mean()
         .unstack('home_dummy')
         .add_prefix('mean_home_')
      )

out['mean_total'] = df.groupby('team').tail(6).groupby('team')['points'].mean()
```

Output:

```
home_dummy    mean_home_0  mean_home_1  mean_total
team                                              
Athlético-PR    29.806667    38.271667   33.108333
```

Another option is to write a udf so as to reduce the two groupby to one:

```
def last6mean(x):
    return x.tail(6).mean()

out = (df.groupby(['team','home_dummy'])['points']
        .apply(last6mean)
        .unstack('home_dummy')
        .add_prefix('mean_home_')
     )

out['mean_total'] = df.groupby('team')['points'].apply(last6mean)
```

Comment: `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`, on `.groupby(['team','home_dummy'])['points'].mean()`

Comment: Make sure the points column is numerical type, e.g float.

Comment: how do I corce it into numeric?

Comment: df['points'] = pd.to_numeric(df['points'], errors='coerce'])?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two dataframes for filtering for the 6 largest with groupby and then get the means and merge together:

First make sure they are numeric:

```
df['round'] = df['round'].astype(int)
df['points'] = df['points'].astype(float)
```

OR

```
df['round'] = pd.to_numeric(df['round'], errors='coerce')
df['points'] = pd.to_numeric(df['points'], errors='coerce')
```

Then, you can run the following:

```
df1 = (df.loc[df.index.isin(df.groupby('team')['round'].nlargest(6).reset_index().iloc[:,1]), 
        ['team', 'points']].groupby('team')['points'].mean().rename('mean_total').reset_index())
df2 = (df.loc[df.index.isin(df.groupby(['team','home_dummy'])['round'].nlargest(6).reset_index().iloc[:,2]), 
        ['team', 'home_dummy', 'points']].groupby(['team','home_dummy'])['points'].mean()
       .unstack(1).add_prefix('mean_home_').reset_index())
df1.merge(df2, on='team')
Out[1]: 
           team  mean_total  mean_home_0  mean_home_1
0  Athlético-PR   33.108333    29.806667    38.271667
```

You could also create a function to make cleaner:

```
def f(df, cols):
    return df.loc[df.index.isin(df.groupby(cols)['round'].nlargest(6).reset_index().iloc[:, len(cols)]), 
        cols + ['points']].groupby(cols)['points'].mean()


(f(df, ['team']).rename('mean_total').reset_index().merge(
    f(df, ['team', 'home_dummy']).unstack(1).add_prefix('mean_home_').reset_index()))
Out[2]: 
       team  mean_total  mean_home_0  mean_home_1
0  Athlético-PR   33.108333    29.806667    38.271667
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object`

Comment: @8-BitBorges `df['round'] = df['round'].astype(int)`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Both answers are quite similar, and show two options. I'll accept the other answer for being simpler, to my opinion, but will certainly upvote yours. thank you so much

Comment: I agree @8-BitBorges . The step Quang used to sort allowed him to use "tail" making it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I know that there's already awesome answers here, but I'd just like to share one using `pivot_table`:

If your DataFrame looks something like this

```
   team  home_dummy  round  points
0     A           0      1       3
1     A           0      2       4
2     A           1      3       7
3     A           1      4       8
4     B           0      1       3
5     B           1      2       6
6     B           1      3       9
7     B           0      4      12
8     C           0      1       5
9     C           1      2       5
10    C           1      3       5
11    C           0      4       5
```

Then you could do something like:

```
N = 2
df['points'] = df['points'].astype(float)

result = df.pivot_table(index='team',
                        columns='home_dummy',
                        values='points',
                        aggfunc=lambda x: x.tail(N).mean())

result.rename({i: f"mean_home_{i}" for i in result.columns}, axis=1, inplace=True)
result.columns.name = None

result['mean_total'] = df.groupby('team').tail(N).groupby('team')['points'].mean()
```

Which will give you the following dataframe

```
      mean_home_0  mean_home_1  mean_total
team                                      
A             3.5          7.5         5.5
B             7.5          7.5         7.5
C             5.0          5.0         5.0
```

Comment: great, thanks for the contribution! Interestingly enough, my original is a pivot table.